# Round Function not working properly in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

Round() is not working properly in crystal reports. I have value 99.52865, I'm rounding the value to 4 decimal places by using Round function. The Function Displaying Value after rounding is 99.5286 but it has to round to 99.5287. For Some values it is rounding properly like 0.40465 to 0.4047. Facing issue for some values only.

Comment: How are you rounding it?

Comment: Im Rounding text field by converting to number. This is the formula I have used. ToText(Round(ToNumber({Table.Field}) ,4),4)

Comment: There is a rule that states that when the "rounding digit" is 5, it will round up or round down depending on the digit to the left (if it is odd or event). But it not seems to be the case.

Comment: The formula what I have used it is not working some times. Roundup function is rounding  the value to up if the value is less than 5 also.